# SQL insert into row based on column value?

Tags: mysql, database

Looking for a query that can add based upon what a certain column returns.... the table looks like this.

```
`skillID` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`class` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`level` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`cap` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

I'm looking for something like this.
UPDATE table SET cap (5+(level*5)) WHERE skillid = 55 AND class = 2 AND level BETWEEN '1' AND '60';

That would be great if that worked lol. I need it to take level and do (5+(level*5)). Basically level 1 should cap = 10, level 2 cap = 15, etc.

I wouldn't ask but after doing 2000 rows last night by hand my carpel tunnel is killing me. with 48000 to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why doesn't this work?

```
UPDATE table
    SET cap = (5+(`level`*5)
    WHERE skillid = 55 AND class = 2 AND `level` BETWEEN 1 AND 60;
```

Comment: I thought it should as well it seems the problem is level is used somehow in heidisql. So it will not do the syntax correctly.

Comment: Adding quotes around level is still producing a warning. Doesn't seem to be pulling the value of level out properly.

Comment: Just needed level to have ` around it.